# TextBox in master page cleared when redirect another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

i have a master page like this:

```
public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string myText
    {
        get { return TextBox1.Text; }
        set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Site1.Master :

```
@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="Project1.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

           <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

           </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and  Default.aspx page like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project1.Default" %>
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Site1.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="testTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

</asp:Content>
```

and i access the TextBox1 control in Default.aspx.cs page like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Master.myText = testTextBox.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
}
```

my problem is in last line , when i go to Page2.aspx myText Cleared! and don't show in Page2.aspx.
What should I do?

Comment: you can add it as a url param like `~/Page2.aspx?val=textBoxValue`

Comment: "What should I do?" - Save it somewhere so that Page2.aspx can get at it.  Options include Session, Cookies, querystring that you append to the Page2.aspx URL.

Comment: i accessed to master page that all pages affected! Even in Page3,Page4 ,... No way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities:

**1) Append it to the next url**

Add a param, like in my example below, eg `val` where you store the text of the TextBox.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Master.myText = testTextBox.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx?val=" + testTextBox.Text);
}
```

You then can get this value in your MasterPage like:

```
private string _Val {
    get {
        return Request["val"] != null ? Request["val"].ToString() : "";
    }
}
```

You can then append the property to your TextBox like:

```
this.myTextBox.Text = _Val;
```

**2) Store it in a Session**

Create the session object.

```
Session["ValText"] = testTextBox.Text;
```

Get the value of the session in your MasterPage using a property:

```
private string _Val {
    get {
        return Session["ValText"] != null ? (string)Session["ValText"] : "";
    }
}
```

You can then append the property to your TextBox like:

```
this.myTextBox.Text = _Val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your TextBox1.Text is cleared when any page of your website is loaded...
Try to store the value in a session variable if you wanna use it in all your website pages.

see this example => http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/